# How to load Google fonts in CakePHP/Using GoogleFontHelper with CakePHP 2.3.6

Tags: cakephp

How can I load Google fonts in CakePHP? I found one helper which is built for CakePHP 2.0. It's here: http://plugins.cakephp.org/p/1277-CakePHP-Font-Plugin

But when I try to integrate it in my AppController using this:

```
public $helpers = array('Session','Html', 'Js', 'Form', 'GoogleFont');
```

, the result is:

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of GoogleFontHelper::url() should be compatible with Helper::url($url = NULL, $full = false) [APP/View/Helper/GoogleFontHelper.php, line 50]
```

So is this GoogleFontHelper incompatible with CakePHP 2.3.6.?

Or is there another way of loading Google fonts?

Comment: I don't understand Your idea, what for Cake Helper for fonts? Import fonts by @import in css files

Comment: `is this GoogleFontHelper incompatible with CakePHP 2.3.6.?` no it's not incompatible, it generates E_STRICT warnings (which are easy to fix). Do you really need that helper? doesn't look like it does much really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am i missing something, why do you need a helper? Cant you just do..

```
echo $this->Html->css('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700');
```

Or add it directly to your css file using `@import` like kicaj says.

Comment: +1 note that the (low value?) helper [does exactly that](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Font-Plugin/blob/master/View/Helper/GoogleFontHelper.php#L23)

Comment: Thank you! I knew that there must be an easy way to load Google fonts, but I couldn't find any solution as I googled...